# Facebook pixel question

Tags: extensions, facebook, facebook-pixel

Ive added the Facebook pixel for Ads and it shows up fine with the catalog of products but how do I get the products to show on the Shop tab in Facebook? Do I need a separate extension for this?

Answer (score 2):

You would require a separate extension. Facebook pixel is for tracking purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a free one?

Comment: No - I've only come across either one-off payment or tiered based on how many items you list.  This is free: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/social.html